# Signal Handler is getting deadlocked

Tags: signals, deadlock

I am developing an application where in I am calling a function every 1 sec. But the program is getting deadlocked and I am not able to find the root cause. Here is my sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

pthread_mutex_t loc;
pthread_t StartProcessThread;
void fun(int t);
void *vStartProcess(void *);

int main()
{
        bool t=true;
        struct itimerspec TimerSpec;
        struct sigaction sa;

        timer_t timerId;

        int        nResult=pthread_mutex_init(&loc,NULL);
        if(nResult!=0)
        {
                perror("failed to initialize the ReportedTrackListLock mutex\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        nResult=pthread_create(&StartProcessThread,NULL,vStartProcess,NULL);
        if(nResult!=0)        //check whether thread got created successfully, if not exit the
application
        {
                printf("Error in creating StartProcessThread thread...exiting the application\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        TimerSpec.it_interval.tv_sec=1;
        TimerSpec.it_interval.tv_nsec=0;
        TimerSpec.it_value.tv_sec=1;
        TimerSpec.it_value.tv_nsec=0;

        sa.sa_handler=&fun;
        sa.sa_flags=0;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

        sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL);

        long a=timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,NULL,&timerId);
        if(a!=0)
        {
                printf("Error in creating the timer...Exiting the application\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        a=timer_settime(timerId,0,(const itimerspec *)&TimerSpec,NULL);
        if(a!=0)
        {
                printf("Error in setting the timer...Exiting the application\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        pthread_join(StartProcessThread,NULL);
}


void fun(int t)
{
        printf("came here\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&loc);
        sleep(2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&loc);
        printf("came here1\n");
}

void *vStartProcess(void *)
{
printf("thread created\n");
        bool t=true;
        while(t)
        {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&loc);
                sleep(1);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&loc);
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Somebody please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Mixing `SIGALRM` and `sleep(3)` is not a good idea, as `sleep(3)` can be implemented with `SIGALRM`. Mutex locking and unlocking is not async-signal safe. Last but not least, there is no guarantee that a signal is delivered to a specific thread; nothing in your code ensures that `SIGALRM` is not delivered to the thread running `vStartProcess()` (and if it is delivered after it locked, the signal handler deadlocks because it waits forever on a mutex). You need to rethink your approach. Why do you need to sleep?

Comment: @Filipe In my actual code I have replaced sleep with some logic. Here I am just trying to show that it takes 2 seconds to complete and also the signal is getting delivered to main thread by default. As far as I know the signal is supposed to get blocked while the handler is running, but here the signal is getting delivered while the handler is running. Can you help me in resolving this issue. I want the signal to be blocked while signal handler is running.

Comment: POSIX allows a signal to be delivered to any thread, so you shouldn't rely on that. But the main problem is that you can't use locking primitives (mutexes, semaphores, etc) inside signal handlers. They are not async-signal safe. If you really need to do this, you have to redesign your code - a common approach is to have a dedicated thread handle all signals synchronously with `sigwait(3)` so that it is safe to use locks. Other threads must block every signal to guarantee delivery to the right thread.

Comment: @Filipe Thanks for the explanation